# Moving the Windows Workflow database: safe enough?

Tags: sql-server

We have a Windows Workflow service that is running in the IIS context and persisting to a database in between hydrates. It has the Tracking Service turned on, as well. We're looking to move the database to another server, and I wanted to make sure there are no gotchas in doing so. My current plan would just be to spin down IIS to stop all activity, back up the database, migrate the database, then flip connection strings in my application to point to the new one.

My main concern was if existing workflows somehow need to stay on the same database or not, or if some activity needs to happen for them to work after the move. I wouldn't think so, but just planning ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the WF hosts are shutdown for the move, and all the necessary connection strings are updated correctly there should be no problem.